# SD card isn't being detected by raspberrypi 3 B+ or my laptop

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, sd-card, power

Raspberrypi 3 B+ was working yesterday, had the raspbian image flashed onto it and I was able to ssh into it headless from my laptop with no major issues. However, today it didn't boot up, so I removed the 16GB sd card I got from the kit and put it into my laptop. Tried lsblk so I could mount the SD card but nothing showed up so I checked my dmesg. Here are a few errors I've got:

```
[  462.442187] mmc0: card never left busy state
[  462.442198] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[  516.839131] audit: type=1101 audit(1640333715.583:95): pid=4356 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_
unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="user" exe="/usr/bin/doas" hostname=user addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
```

...

```
[ 1546.854625] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[ 1546.959287] mmc0: invalid bus width
[ 1546.959297] mmc0: error -22 whilst initializing SD card
```

Comment: Replace your SDCard the one you've got is dead or a fake.

Comment: Kind of suspected that, but it's kind of absurd that I got this kit from element14, works for a day completely fine, then dies immediately the next morning.

Comment: Could be a dud. Contact element14 for a replacement.